# Math journal for high school students?

Tags: mathematics-education, journals

I recently discovered [The College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/pubs/cmj.html) and enjoyed reading through some of the articles on fun applications of mathematics. I'd like to send some of the articles to my younger sister, a high school sophomore, but unfortunately most of them require calculus, a subject she hasn't studied yet.

Are there any other journals or websites that publish quality articles on applied math that a high school student taking pre-calculus could understand reasonably well?

Comment: Related: [Journals for undergraduates](http://mathoverflow.net/q/36850).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An excellent journal published by the University of New South Wales (my alma mater!) is [Parabola](http://www.parabola.unsw.edu.au/content/about-us), aimed at interested secondary students.

Answer (score 7):

Mathematical Mayhem was a math journal intended for and run by high school and university students.  It now runs as a section within the journal [Crux Mathematicorum](https://cms.math.ca/crux/), published by the Canadian Math Society.  It looks like the Math Mayhem section is accessible without a subscription.  However, the focus seems to be on problem-solving, so maybe it isn't what you're looking for, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: I love journals like this, which focus on problem solving and seems like Crux Mathematicorum is the only one of this kind. This answer was made more than a decade ago so it's worth mentioning now that Crux Mathematicorum is now a free magazine for all lovers of Problem Solving !

Answer (score 7):

There is one dead journal [Quantum](http://www.nsta.org/quantum/)

Comment: Its content is available at ProQuest: http://proquest.umi.com/pqdweb?RQT=318&pmid=36072 (paid subscription).


Comment: @PashaZusmanovich everything is freely available at their homepage http://www.nsta.org/publications/quantum.aspx

Comment: They also used to have a great correspondence school at that journal for high school kids.

Answer (score 5):

The most popular resource among the students at the [MathPath](http://www.mathpath.org/) summer camp seems to be the web site [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/).  (I also highly recommend summer camps such as MathPath, although that particular one is for ages 11-14.  In my impression, the four most venerated choices at the high school level are MathCamp, Promys, Ross, and Hampshire.  It may be challenging to get into these; the AMS maintains [an extended list](http://www.ams.org/employment/mathcamps.html).)

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't particularly  pay attention to the opportunities available at the high school level, and the four programs you named are the four I've heard of.

Comment: These are probably the four that tend to show up in the vitas of mathematicians.  Also, reputation always has a degree of self-fulfillment.  


Answer (score 5):

There is a Hungarian mathematics (and physics) journal for high-school students (KöMaL); I think it's mostly in Hungarian, but there are some [English articles](http://www.komal.hu/cikkek/cikkekrol.e.shtml) on their homepage, and there are some special issues in English. They also have running competitions, which are definitely available in English (for the last 40 years or so!). There is an archive of old issues, which seems to contain English material as well, but unfortunately it is not working at the moment...

Answer (score 4):

[Plus Magazine](http://plus.maths.org/) by the University of Cambridge is another great resource.

Answer (score 4):

The Girls' Angle Bulletin is another great resource with lots of interesting articles about math aimed at a pre-college level. It's especially nice because the style of writing is informal and the articles span a wide variety of mathematical topics. All the past issues are available for free online: 
http://www.girlsangle.org/page/bulletin.php

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical Digest published by the university of Cape Town.

http://www.math.uct.ac.za/mam/outreach/digest/archive

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly German language, but *[die Wurzel](http://www.wurzel.org)*, published at the University of Jena, holds a pretty high quality. If you can read German, (or want to learn) I can recommend it warmly.

Similar journals exist in Hungary, Poland and Russia.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested I have recently created a journal of mathematics exclusively for high school students. It is called the High School Journal of Mathematics and you can view the website here (https://hsmathjournal.wordpress.com/), and we publish articles and research on any mathematical topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In French : Tangente and for very good high school pupils and undergraduates : Quadrature.

Answer (score 1):

Many journals have expository and survey articles that can be read by high school students.

Some of these are listed here:

http://www.york.cuny.edu/~malk/biblio/journals-biblio.html

Best.

Joe Malkevitch

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started a mathematics section of Frontiers for Young Minds [http://kids.frontiersin.org], a journal in which kids (ages 8-15) are not only the target audience but also the referees.  The section is very new and we do not yet have any articles, but I hope that will change before long!

Comment: Do you have an editorial policy (e.g word length, articles by kids for kids, no prerequisites and only one or two basic concepts included, mathematical maturity encouraged but not required)? I could be induced to contribute a short article. Gerhard "Will Write For Venti Mochas" Paseman, 2017.06.23.

Comment: I managed to find the website https://kids.frontiersin.org independently. The impression I get is that articles are accepted only from career scientists or those with an established publication record.  If and when you have a broader acceptance policy, I may consider a submission.  I am willing to contribute topic suggestions and other material if you are really pressed for it.  Gerhard "Never Was About The Career" Paseman, 2017.06.23.

Comment: Gerhard, thanks for your interest!  The author's specific credentials are less important to me than the quality and suitability of the article for this audience.  You do not necessarily have to be a career scientist or mathematician per se.  (I know the website says "articles by distinguished scientists," but I intend to interpret that broadly.)  I'd be keen to hear both topic suggestions and (especially) article submissions.  Perhaps we can continue this discussion by e-mail; I am reachable at jlmartin@ku.edu.